# Checksum of large file with emacs

Tags: emacs, checksum

How do you compute the md5 checksum of a large `.zip` file in emacs?  I want to do something like:

`(secure-hash 'md5 (insert-file-contents "~/blah/blah.zip"))`

and just get out my 128-bit hash.  I'm not sure what function to use to visit a large file (say 400 MB) without needing to read the file into a buffer.

UPDATE: thought I would just add a quick workaround function since from the answer it seems `secure-hash` won't work for large files.  I downloaded fciv.exe for windows, added that to the exec-path and use this function from emacs.

```
(defun checksum (FILE &optional exe)
  (let* ((default "fciv")
         (EXE (if (and exe (executable-find exe)) exe default) )
         (call (concat EXE " " FILE) ) )
    (if (executable-find EXE)
        (progn
          (if (and exe (not (equal exe default) ) )
              (message (concat "'" exe "' not found, using " default) ) )
          (call-process-shell-command call nil t nil) )
      (progn
        (message "Hashing program not found in exec-path")
        nil) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs only operates on data in strings or in buffers.  So either you bring the whole file into a buffer (like in your code), or you use an external tool via something like `call-process`.

Comment: Not necessarily — you could read the file in chunks, using the `beg` and `end` arguments of `insert-file-contents`.

Comment: Indeed, you could, but it's not clear how you'd pass that to md5, then.